# ECG processing using arduino

Tags: arduino

We are doing a project on ECG signal extraction.We got the extraction and it is full of noise(50 hz) so we need to process the signal and we are proposed to process it via arduino board.we need to denoise it by using arduino.

How can we do ECG processing using arduino board and which arduino board is perfectly suitable with less cost and more accuracy and that arduino should be small?

Comment: An Arduino is not powerful to be used as a real time DSP, even for audio signals. What you need, over at http://electronics.stackexchange.com is to ask for an **analog 50Hz notch filter**.

Comment: Take a look at this: https://www.dsprelated.com/code.php?submittedby=56840

Answer (score 0):

There are chips that will do this for you. such as the ADS1294 and alike.

Where such chips are typical in that they are differential amplifiers that eliminate the common modem noise such as 50Hz. Rather than a notch filter. As much of the desired signal is in the 50Hz range. ECG schematic is very standard in that they amplify the difference between Right Arm and Left Arm, where the Left Leg is a common mode reference. They go further to inject an offset into the Right Leg as to prevent common modem offset from saturating. Elektor Magazine's recent July/August 2013 Issue has a through explanation of their ECG board. Where there are other sources on the web for these.

Comment: can we use arduino instead of this chips because we are much interested in arduino and is there a possibility for wireless transmission using arduino? If possible can you give me the arduino details and how to program it?

Comment: You need an Analog Front End (AFE) Interface to pick up the ECG. The Arduino itself won't do that sufficiently. As you need a Diff Amp as stated above. to at least remove the 60Hz. Look at the data sheet for the ADS1294 as a starter to see the functional diagram of the proper AFE. Additionally look at other AFE examples [ECG Images](https://www.google.com/search?q=ecg+schematic&tbm=isch&tbo=u&source=univ&sa=X&ei=aOs5Upe1B7W24AOZkYGoBA&ved=0CEAQsAQ&biw=1034&bih=751&dpr=1)

Answer (score 0):

You don't necessarily need a hardware filter. A software filter will work just fine. The lowpass/highpass filter from the [Pan Tompkins Algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pan%E2%80%93Tompkins_algorithm) uses only integer math and is therefore not very resource intensive.

To do Pan Tompkins in real time, you need to store 13 points of both input history and lowpass history. One points of highpass history is stored. The 13 points can be stored in an array, but I find a circular buffer is really good. I used the [CircularBuffer](https://www.arduino.cc/reference/en/libraries/circularbuffer/) library, but there are other implementations. Here's the relevant code for filtering:

```
CircularBuffer<int,33> inp;
CircularBuffer<int,33> lpfout;
int raw;
int filt; 

//preload buffers with zeros (this is pretty important)
for (int i = 0; i <= 32; i++) {
    //sig = analogRead(A0);
    inp.unshift(0);
    lpfout.unshift(0);
}

raw = analogRead(A0);
inp.unshift(raw);

//lowpass filter
filt = 2*lpfout[0] - lpfout[1] + inp[0] - 2*inp[6] + inp[12];
lpfout.unshift(filt);  // this becomes lpfout[0] for the next loop

//highpass filter
filt = hpfout1 - lpfout[0]/32 + lpfout[16] - lpfout[17] + lpfout[32]/32;
hpfout1 = filt;

//filt now holds the real time filtered signal
```

This code runs fast. In the original Pan Tompkins paper, they sampled the ECG at 200 Hz, so I set up my loop to send data over the serial port at 200 Hz. I don't see any drops, so the Arduino has no problem keeping up.